# Create one json object from two different json objects

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I have two JSON responses coming from two different columns as per below:

I am using .NET Core and JsonSerializer and JsonDeserializer of system.text.json.

I am thinking to create class with all details and then merge into one JSON object and deserialize it, but I am not sure what steps will make it easier for me.

First JSON is below:

```
{
  "Test1": {
    "2020": [
      "10%",
      "10%",
      "10%",
      "10%"
    ],
    "2021": [
      "10%",
      "30%",
      "30%",
      "40%"
    ]
  },
  "Test2": {
    "2020": [
      "No",
      "No",
      "No",
      "No"
    ],
    "2021": [
      "No",
      "No",
      "No",
      "No"
    ]
  }
}
```

Second JSON is below:

```
{
  "Test3": [
    {
      "2020": [
        "LC",
        "Cnd",
        "NA",
        "LC"
      ],
      "2021": [
        "LC",
        "Cd",
        "NA",
        "Lty"
      ]
    },
  ],
}
```

Now I want to return both JSON objects into 1 JSON format and it will look like this:

```
{
  "Mainjson1": {"Test1": {
    "2020": [
      "10%",
      "10%",
      "10%",
      "10%"
    ],
    "2021": [
      "10%",
      "30%",
      "30%",
      "40%"
    ]
  },
  "Test2": {
    "2020": [
      "No",
      "No",
      "No",
      "No"
    ],
    "2021": [
      "No",
      "No",
      "No",
      "No"
    ]
  }
  },
  "Secondjson2": {"Test3": {
    "2020": [
      "10%",
      "10%",
      "10%",
      "10%"
    ],
    "2021": [
      "10%",
      "30%",
      "30%",
      "40%"
    ]
  },
  "Test4": {
    "2020": [
      "No",
      "No",
      "No",
      "No"
    ],
    "2021": [
      "No",
      "No",
      "No",
      "No"
    ]
  }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use **JObject**.

I will give you a small example:

For example lets declare two JSON strings.

```
string json1 = "Your First JSON";
string json2 = "Your Second JSON";
```

Deserialize JSON strings into JObject instances.

```
    JObject jObject1 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JObject>(json1);
    JArray jArray2 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JArray>(json2);
```

Create the combined structure

```
    JObject combinedJson = new JObject();
    combinedJson.Add("Mainjson1", jObject1);
    combinedJson.Add("Secondjson2", jArray2[0]);
```

Serialize the combined JObject back to a JSON string

```
    string combinedJsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(combinedJson, Formatting.Indented);
```

This example is for the current JSON you want to create.

If you want to use it more dynamically, try look into JObject.